# How to configure pspell extension in WAMP (php spell checker)

Tags: php, wampserver, spell-checking, pspell

I am trying to configure my WAMPServer to use PHP Spellchecker.

As stated I installed `ASPELL/PSPELL` from http://aspell.net/win32/ and tried configuring the extension.
But I am unable to do it.

In every forum they have asked to install `ASPELL/PSPELL`, but the (`.dll`) file I get is `aspell-15.dll` and `pspell-15.dll`

But in the Wampserver the extension is named as `php_pspell.dll`.

I tried renaming it but the extension is not getting loaded.

Can anyone please help me here.